# Filtering by a Value with a button

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a button that will look for a value in a particular column and filter by it.

I have 7 columns with data and on the top row i would like to create something like a search bar/ column filtering button. The idea is enter a value in Cell B2 and click a button to have the column G sorted by the value in B2.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort by a value"? Is the value in B2 the name of the column you want to sort by? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Record a macro to sort the range and then simply amend it to accept a value :) Give it a try and if you are stuck then simply post the code that you tried and we will take it from there...

Comment: It is. I cannot make you en example right now, but check: http://www.get-digital-help.com/excel-sort-using-array-formulas/

Comment: I wonder if you actually mean "filter by a value" rather than sort, since "sorting by a value" doesn't make sense for a column.

Comment: @Floris: Yeah. I guess you are right. I thought the user was referring to the Sort Key :)

Comment: I don’t think I explain my idea correctly, thank you for taking your time to reply. The button i want to create is will do the same thing as the filter; where you select only the data that you want to view--in this case the value in B2 and filter everything else out. The main idea is to have the user type their name on B2 and hit enter, and then the macro will activate the filter to only show whatever has his name in column G. There is a reason to my madness, I work with an older staff that is not too savvy when it comes to excel, and using a text filter is unheard of.

Comment: Now that you have explained it - we can do better than a button. You can actually run the filter macro when an event (SheetChange) is triggered because a cell changed. Confirm that the changed cell is B2, and you can get rid of the button. Do you know how to do that or do you need more help? `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    MsgBox "run the filter" ' replace with call to filter function
  End If
End Sub` . You would add this code to the WORKSHEET (not a workbook module) with obvious changes as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly that by "sort" you mean "filter", then you can do the following.

Create a button on your sheet (Developer tab on the ribbon, insert... button),

[image]

and when prompted, add the following code to the `Button_Click()` Sub :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
  [G:G].AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Range("b2").Value 
End Sub
```

Be careful that you don't put your button on a row that might get "filtered" or it will disappear. Also, if your "sort on this value" field is in row 2, it might disappear as well.

I'm sure you can figure out how to deal with those things.

**Alternative interpretation of question**

If instead you are looking to sort on a particular column, whose name is given in cell B2, then your code might look something like this:

```
Option Compare Text
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim sortCol As Integer
Dim headerRange As Range
Dim sortRange as Range

' assuming data to be sorted is in columns E through K
set headerRange = [E1:K1] ' or wherever the headers are
sortCol = WorksheetFunction.Match([B2].Value, headerRange)
' this line for debug:
set sortRange = [E:E].Offset(, sortCol - 1)
MsgBox "you will sort by column " & sortRange.Address

With ActiveSheet
    .Range("E:K").Select
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sortRange, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With .Sort
    .SetRange Range("E:K")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for going the extra mile :)

Comment: Inspired by your comment, @SiddharthRout !

Comment: thank you, I had to change it to the below, now it works like a charm!                                Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    [G:G].AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Range("b2").Value
End Sub

Comment: OK - I updated the answer to mirror your input - it will be more useful for future visitors that way. Glad it worked.